# How can I use mysqldump to replicate views between accounts?

Tags: mysql

I'm using **mysqldump** to replicate a database between accounts on a particular machine.  Everything works just great, except when we get to our defined views.  Because the dump includes a line like the following ...

```
/*!50013 DEFINER=`user_a`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
```

... when loading the dump into mysql on user_b we receive an error:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 657: Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation
```

Needless to say, I don't have SUPER privilege on this mysql instance.  Is there a way to convince **mysqldump** to dump the views in a user-agnostic way?  I can't find anything in the manual on this point.   Do I have to actually parse the dumpfile to replace the usernames?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

same problem. I solved it that way:

```
mysqldump -uuser1 -ppassword1 database1 > backup.sql

sed '/^\/\*\!50013 DEFINER/d' backup.sql > backup_without_50013.sql

mysql -u user2 -ppassword2 -D database2 < backup_without_50013.sql
```

The interesting thing is the [sed](http://soft.zoneo.net/Linux/remove_comment_lines.php) command which, here, removes all lines beginning with /*!50013.

Heidy

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up doing the same thing, except using grep -v instead of sed, but the result was the same. :)

Answer (score 12):

You will need to process the backup file and change the DEFINER:

DEFINER=`user_a`@`localhost`

I like to change it to :

DEFINER=CURRENT_USER

It will then be automatically associated to the account that loads it.

Comment: thanks for the tip!
I use (I need to escape the `): sed -ri s/DEFINER=\`[^\`]+\`@\`%\`/DEFINER=CURRENT_USER/g file.sql

Comment: This! And with a little `sed` magic from @brunoqc it's just perfect

Answer (score 2):

The SQL SECURITY clauses determine which MySQL account to use when checking access privileges for the view (as you have probably figured out).

When you create a view you can define a couple of options for security for that view.  You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), but essentially by default access is restricted to the 'definer' of the view, i.e. the user who created it.

Comment: Thanks, Max.  I checked it out, and it doesn't seem that tinkering with these options affects the way mysqldump produces output.  If it would simply omit the DEFINER line, I would be golden. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `mysqldump` with the option `"--skip-triggers"`

Comment: Interesting idea, but this doesn't do anything to affect the @DEFINER lines in the dump output.  As long as I'm asserting a definer other than the logged-in MySQL user, I get the security error.