# Import triggers from a mysql dump file

Tags: mysql, import, triggers, delimiter

I have encountered an unpleasant situation on a shared host. I was trying to import a database dump that contained several triggers. Upon executing

```
DELIMITER ;;
```

phpMyAdmin returned an error, stating that in order to change the delimiter, I need SUPER privileges.

However, when I manually typed the trigger create queries: (example)

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_user AFTER INSERT ON user FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO priv (uid,role) VALUES (NEW.id,'guest');
END;;
```

everything works absolutely fine.

Is there a way to get around this issue on a shared host (ie, I cannot gain root privileges for my database user), or will I be forced to manually copy the trigger creation queries each time I'm transferring the database from a local server to the production one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use mysqldump to replicate views between accounts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154332/how-can-i-use-mysqldump-to-replicate-views-between-accounts)